# Rvest and Failed to Connect

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

My wife would like to capture all of the entries for a medical blog we had online.  I thought this would be a good opportunity to try out webscraping since copy paste would take forever.  My code is below:

```
library(rvest)
url <- "http://www.carepages.com/"
pgsession <-html_session(url)
pgform <- html_form(pgsession)[[1]]
filled_form <- set_values(pgform,
                  'session[email]' = "myemail@email.com"
                  'session[password]' = "mypassword")
submit_form(pgsession,filled_form)
```

However, when I run this, I get an

Error in curl::curl_fetch_memory(url, handle = handle) : 
  Failed to connect to www.carepages.com port 80: Timed out

Can't even get into the page to try out scraping each blog.

Answer (score 0):

The first error that should have occurred with the code as presented was

```
Error: unexpected string constant in:
    "                'session[email]' = "myemail@email.com"
                    'session[password]'"
```

... which relates to a missing comma after `"myemail@email.com"`

Use the second form on htat page instead:

```
pgform <- html_form(pgsession)[[2]]
filled_form <- set_values(pgform,
                  'session[email]' = "myemail@email.com"
                  'session[password]' = "mypassword")
```

Comment: The comma was an oversight when I pasted so that is ok now.  Changed the second part and now I get an

Error in as.vector(y): object 'pgform' not found 

and then

Error in lapply(x,f):Object 'filled_form' not found

Comment: Not much more I can do as far as tested code goes, since I'm pretty sure those are not valid email and password values. Seems clear that the `pgform` object should exist. When I look at it with str() I see that neither `email` nor `password` are field names.

Comment: AND... I think you should be working with the second form object rather than the 1st. There one does see a named filed of `"session[email]"`

Comment: Thanks for looking into it.  I played around with it last night and tried all sorts of iterations but just could not get it to work in R.  Used a different web scraper without issue so I'll just go forward with that.  I had hoped to use this as a "training" experience but looks like it won't work.